# Fan sporadically maxed on wake-up due to unavailable sensor temperature

Tags: thinkpad, fan, temperature, sensors, lm-sensors

I'm running Kubuntu on my Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon (4th generation). Since a recent upgrade to 20.04 LTS, I have the following problem.

Upon wake-up from standby the laptop's fan is sporadically set on max speed (around 7000 RPM) regardless of the actual CPU load. It helps to put the laptop to sleep and wake it up again. Then there is a chance the fan will react normally to CPU load and temperature.

Running `sensors` when the fan is maxed, I get the following:

```
$ sensors
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +35.0°C  

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +42.5°C  

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          16.97 V  

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        6932 RPM
temp1:            N/A  
temp2:            N/A  
temp3:         +0.0°C  
temp4:         +0.0°C  
temp5:         +0.0°C  
temp6:         +0.0°C  
temp7:         +0.0°C  
temp8:         +0.0°C  
temp9:         +0.0°C  
temp10:        +1.0°C  
temp11:        +0.0°C  
temp12:        +0.0°C  
temp13:        +0.0°C  
temp14:        +0.0°C  
temp15:        +0.0°C  
temp16:        +0.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +48.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
```

And running it when the fan behaves normally, i.e. in accordance with the CPU load, I notice that `temp1` is no longer `N/A` but has a value.

```
...
thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        3240 RPM
temp1:        +46.0°C  
temp2:            N/A  
...
```

Any ideas what could be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't know how to fix it, but I have the same issue with a 5th generation x1 on archlinux (i.e. the fan runs max speed iff temp1 is unavailable, which sometimes happens after wakening up from suspend)

Comment: I posted the bug here https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=210457 and slowly something seems to happen with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For now, as a workaround, I have moved to using `thinkfan` (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/thinkfan.1.html) which can be configured not to use the disappearing temp value.